# Get a random character from a string and append to another string

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to write the Rust equivalent of the following C++ code:

```cpp
result += consonants[rand() % consonants.length()];
```

It is meant to take a random character from the string `consonants` and append it to the string `result`.

I seem to have found a working Rust equivalent, but it's... monstrous, to say the least. What would be a more idiomatic equivalent?

```
format!("{}{}", result, consonants.chars().nth(rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, consonants.chars().count())).unwrap().to_string());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things:

- You don't need to use `format!()` here. There is [`String::push()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push) which appends a single char.
- There is also the [`rand::sample()`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.3.15/rand/fn.sample.html) function which can randomly choose multiple elements from an iterator. This looks like the perfect fit!

So let's see how this fits together! I created three different versions for different use cases.

#### 1. Unicode string (the general case)

```
let consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
let mut result = String::new();

result.push(rand::sample(&mut rand::thread_rng(), consonants.chars(), 1)[0]);
//                                                                    |  |
//                             sample one element from the iterator --+  |
//                                                                       |
//                      get the first element from the returned vector --+
```

([Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=ca8401b177b4f04cf8706e6ddb0957ea&version=undefined))

We sample only one element from the iterator and immediately push it to the string. Still not as short as with C's `rand()`, but please note that [`rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) for any kind of serious use! Using C++'s `<random>` header is a lot better, but will require a little bit more code, too. Additionally, your C version can't handle multi-byte characters (e.g. UTF-8 encoding), while the Rust version has full UTF-8 support.

#### 2. ASCII string

However, if you only want to have a string with English consonants, then UTF-8 is not needed and we can make use of O(1) indexing, by using a byte slice:

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

let consonants = b"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
let mut result = String::new();

result.push(thread_rng().choose(consonants).cloned().unwrap().into());
//      convert Option<&u8> into Option<u8> ^^^^^^   
// unwrap, because we know `consonants` is not empty ^^^^^^
//                                   convert `u8` into `char` ^^^^
```

([Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=a8427751b47fc60e177ebddf08482b19&version=undefined))

#### 3. Collection of characters with Unicode support

As mentioned in the comments, you probably just want a collection of characters ("consonants"). This means, we don't have to use a string, but rather an array of `chars`. So here is one last version which does have UTF-8 support *and* avoids O(n) indexing:

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

// If you need to avoid the heap allocation here, you can create a static
// array like this: let consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', ...];
let consonants: Vec<_> = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".chars().collect();
let mut result = String::new();

result.push(*thread_rng().choose(&consonants).unwrap());
```

([Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=2aaa49f4a890db23afe133a538ffcabf&version=undefined))

Comment: `rand::sample(rng, iterable, 1)` has different complexity than `array[rand() % array.size()]` because it has to iterate through the iterator every time anew. It would probably be more efficient to make `consonants` a Vec and use `consonants[rng.gen_range(0, consonants.len())]` or equivalent.

Comment: @user4815162342 You are right. Especially when OP doesn't need UTF-8 support (e.g. only English consonants), we can use constant time indexing. I added a new version which does exactly that!

Comment: Thanks! An option that retains good performance characterisics will still supporting non-ASCII consonants is [`let consonants = "...".chars().collect::<Vec<_>>()`](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=a1cceb0758634e614cc4daac5cef60da&version=undefined).

Comment: OP doesn't mention why they are using a string, but it could be because they want to have a collection of characters. I'd suggest a literal array in that case.

Comment: Whoa, thanks so much, Lukas/guys! I really appreciate the thought that went into the answer, and the multiple solutions offered for me to compare. It's really helpful for a beginning Rust developer like myself. I'd never have thought of a vector of chars, but that's exactly what I'm after. Thanks again. :)